# What part of speech is "mountain" in the sentence "Avalanches are dangerous to mountain climbers."?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I'm trying to understand the grammar of this sentence:

> Avalanches are dangerous to mountain climbers.

What part of speech is the word mountain?

Comment: Basically, it's a noun used as an adjective.  The precise term used for this arrangement depends on your religion.

Comment: It's a noun functioning as complement (not modifier) of climbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the noun phrase "mountain climbers", which is itself the complement of the sentence. Specifically "mountain" is a [noun](https://www.grammar.com/noun-modifiers/) [modifier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noun_modifier)  (also called an 'attributive noun' or a 'noun adjunct'), modifying "climbers". A noun modifier is a kind of noun.

Comment: Surely the NP "mountain climbers" is complement of the preposition "to", thus "to mountain climbers" is a PP. The PP then serves as complement of the adjective "dangerous". "Mountain" is a complement (not modifier) of "climbers".

Comment: Is that still the case when there is no preposition as in "Mountain climbers have to be physically fit"?

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, "mountain" can only be a complement of "climbers" (_climbers of mountains_). Other examples include "a linguistics student" (_a student of linguistics_) / "a flower seller" (_a seller of flowers_) / "a legal advisor" (_an advisor on legal matters_).

Comment: @BillJ I'm Ok with that, it's just that you said it was the complement of 'to' and I thought that was strange.

Comment: @BoldBen The NP "mountain climbers" is complement of the prep "to". What else could it be?

Answer (score -1):

In the context of this sentence, "mountain" is an adjective because it modifies (or describes) the noun, "climbers." It tells *what kind of* climbers they are. Are they ***tree*** climbers? No, they are ***mountain*** climbers!

Comment: Nope, it's a noun. If it were an adjective you'd modify it with an adverb like quickly mountain climbers or very mountain climbers. Those are ungrammatical because it's a noun so needs an adjective; easy mountain climbers, high mountain climbers.